# Is it possible to run jupyter from nside a virtual env

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

For now I was only using python 2.7 (installed for all users, added to path, windows 10 machine) but I want to switch to 3.8, to be able to use both of them I first installed virtualenv in my system python 2.7.

Then installed python 3.8.1 for all user without adding it to path.

Created my virtualenv like that : `virtualenv c:\virtualEnvs\p38x64_jupytertest -p C:\Python38-32\python.exe`

- then activated it : `C:\virtualEnvs\p38x64_jupytertest\Scripts\activate.bat`
- checked if python 3.8.1 was selected with : `python --version` (it was)
- then installed jupyter inside my virtualenv : `pip install jupyter`

Then when I ran `jupyter notebook` I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python38-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\virtualEnvs\p38x64_jupytertest3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\virtualenvs\p38x64_jupytertest3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 268, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "c:\virtualenvs\p38x64_jupytertest3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 663, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<c:\virtualenvs\p38x64_jupytertest3\lib\site-packages\decorator.py:decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "c:\virtualenvs\p38x64_jupytertest3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\virtualenvs\p38x64_jupytertest3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1720, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "c:\virtualenvs\p38x64_jupytertest3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1482, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "c:\virtualenvs\p38x64_jupytertest3\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 152, in listen
    self.add_sockets(sockets)
  File "c:\virtualenvs\p38x64_jupytertest3\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 165, in add_sockets
    self._handlers[sock.fileno()] = add_accept_handler(
  File "c:\virtualenvs\p38x64_jupytertest3\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 279, in add_accept_handler
    io_loop.add_handler(sock, accept_handler, IOLoop.READ)
  File "c:\virtualenvs\p38x64_jupytertest3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 99, in add_handler
    self.asyncio_loop.add_reader(fd, self._handle_events, fd, IOLoop.READ)
  File "C:\Python38-32\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 501, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

After some googling I find a lot of tutorial that explain how to install jupyter in you system python then add virtualenvs to it, but not how to install it INSIDE a virtual env.

The reason I did that is because I want my python 3 project to be isolated since I have a lot of python 2.7 projects (up until now I was not using virtualenv and every package is installed in my system python 2.)

Any idea of why I have this exception?

Thanks.

PS : yes it says `p38x64_jupytertest3` in the stacktrace because the venv is not `p38x64_jupytertest` but `p38x64_jupytertest3` in fact

Comment: This should work. I'm not sufficiently familiar with Windows to know what could be different there. One suspicion I have is that the `pip` you're running is an external one and not the one inside the virtualenv.

Comment: I ran `pip freeze` then `deactivate.bat` then `pip freeze` again and they both show different thing (a lot more outside of the venv), so it looks lile my pip is corretly inside the virtual env

Comment: Sounds correct there.

Answer (score 1):

know issue : https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4613

Reverting to python 3.7 for the moment